# Zero reference point in Darknet YOLO

Tags: darknet, yolo

I'm trying to manually create label files for some images in YOLO/Darknet, and I need to fill in some values for the bounding boxes.

From the YOLO website (https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/):

> Now we need to generate the label files that Darknet uses. Darknet wants a .txt file for each image with a line for each ground truth object in the image that looks like:
>
> [object-class] [x] [y] [width] [height]
>
> Where x, y, width, and height are relative to the image's width and height.

The class, width and height are straight forward, but I'm wondering how to represent the center coordinates for the box, [x] and [y] , as I don't know where the (0,0) reference is allocated.

Thanks

Comment: Not just yolo, but in the world of image processing, the (0,0) coordinates is ALWAYS the top left corner of the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For others who might be wondering, I found the answer to be at the top left corner of the image.